# Prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with prime constant polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, polynomial-rings

Let $P ◅ \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a prime ideal with $P \cap \mathbb{Z} = p\mathbb{Z}$, for a prime number $p$. I have proved by looking at the natural homomorphism 
$$\phi : \mathbb{Z}[X] \longrightarrow \mathbb{F}_p[X]
$$ that takes all coefficients modulo $p$, that $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(p) \cong \mathbb{F}_p[X]$. As $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ is an integral domain, $(p) ⊆ \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a prime ideal. Suppose $P ≠ (p)$, and let $\bar{P} := \phi[P]$. Then, as $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ is a PID, there exists an $\overline{f_p} ∈ \mathbb{F}_p[X]$ such that $\bar{P} = (\overline{f_p})$. I would like this $\overline{f_p}$ to be irreducible (or, equivalently, $f_p$ to be irreducible modulo $p$), and that $f_p$ together with $p$ generate $P$. What am I missing?

Comment: Please write the full question in the text, not only in the title (at least for parts of it). Also, please state explicitly what we have and what we want to show, then the own thoughts how to get the result. In other words, please isolate the result that gives rise to the question, than the question in a compact manner, than the own thoughts.

Comment: Have you looked at [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx/174713#174713)? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The map $\phi$ you have constructed is surjective. Thus, the image of prime ideals is prime (see [A proof that shows surjective homomorphic image of prime ideal is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292829/a-proof-that-shows-surjective-homomorphic-image-of-prime-ideal-is-prime)). This means (as you say) that $\overline{P} = (\overline{f_p})$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ and thus $f_p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Now, let $\psi: \mathbb{F}_p[x] \to \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f_p(x))$ denote the canonical projection. Consider the composition $\psi \circ \phi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f_p(x))$. This map is surjective and has kernel $(p,f_p(x))$. Note that the image of $P$ under $\psi \circ \phi$ is trivial in the quotient. Thus, $P \subseteq (p,f_p(x))$. Moreover, since $p,f_p(x) \in P$ we have $(p,f_p(x)) = P$

Comment: @Arturo Magidin It seems like prime ideals that satisfy this property are necessarily maximal?

Comment: No: $(p)$ has the property, but is not maximal. But other prime ideals, yes, because they will contain $(p)$, and prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ have height at most 2.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin True, so the polynomial you pick to generate $\overline{P}$ could be $0$